# 3D wireframe in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, 3d, wireframe

I would like to create somthing like this

```
 o---o---o
 |   |   |
 o---o---o
(o are points, -- | are lines)
```

In short a wirefrime. I have a bunch of points of which i know the coordinates and now i would like to connect them to form a wireframe. I am really new to wpf and have no idea how to start on this. Does anyone have an idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've answered a similar question about wireframe models here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765841/wireframe-rendering-in-wpf/31331995#31331995][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765841/wireframe-rendering-in-wpf/31331995#31331995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free Helix 3D Toolkit (http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com) is a great start for WPF 3D.

Comment: Is there some sort of tutorial for this helix toolkit? Because the codeplex website offers little help. And I cannot open the examples so any suggestions. this toolkit looks pretty promising but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Thanks figured it out more or less. Do you know if it is possible to make a Point3D(visual3D oject) clickable?

Comment: unchecked the right answer for this question. the helix toolkit was a nice try but does not really bring what I need. Any ideas on how to program this myself. Just need to figure out how to draw shapes (points and lines) and make them clickable